# Space at the end of a page when generating tables?

Tags: prawn

I am generating tables using prawn and I would like it to jump to the next page a little bit sooner to leave me more space to put in a footer in the document. Any ideas? there are multiple tables in PDF so it would be hard to do it with absolute values or by creating a new table in the next page myself

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the bottom margin of the page to leave more space for the footer.

> The default margin for pages is 0.5 inch but you can change that with the :margin option or if
>   you'd like to have different margins you can use the :left_margin, :right_margin,
>   :top_margin, :bottom_margin options.

From the Prawn manual page 92 
[Prawn Manual](http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf)